# Thread scheduling under non-uniform memory access times

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, cpu-architecture

The specifics are obviously OS dependent, but I'm looking for algorithms that are used to assign threads to physical cores for *[non-uniform memory access architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access)* (i.e. accessing different addresses takes different amounts of time. This could be, for instance, because the cache has been divided into physically distributed slices, each placed at a different location and therefore, each has a different access time based on the distance from the core).

Obviously, the scheduler also takes into account things like the number of threads already assigned to the processor among many other variables, but I'm specifically looking for scheduling algorithms that primarily try to minimize memory access time in NUMA architectures.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I am an expert on the topic - I am not - but so far no one else seems eager to answer, so I will give it my best shot.

It would make sense to assume that, on a NUMA system, it would be beneficial to keep running a thread on the same core as long as possible. This would essentially mean a weak form of [processor affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity), where the scheduler decides on which core a thread should be run and may change it dynamically.

Basic scheduling with processor affinity is easy enough to implement: you just take an existing scheduling algorithm and modify it in such a way that each core has its own thread queue (or queues). On a NUMA system, the rest is a matter of determining when it is beneficial to migrate a thread onto another core; I don't think it is possible to give a generally applicable algorithm for that, because the benefits and costs are highly dependent on the specifics of the system in question.

Note that the kind of processor affinity the scheduler would need is *weak* and *automatic*: to which core a thread is pinned is entirely up to the scheduler and may change whenever the scheduler considers it beneficial. This is in sharp contrast to processor affinity in, for example, the Linux scheduler, where processor affinity is *hard* (a thread *cannot* be run on a core it doesn't have affinity with) and *manually* managed by the user (see [sched_setaffinity](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity) and [pthread_setaffinity_np](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_setaffinity_np)).

Comment: The OP is asking about scheduling algorithms that *don't* require you to manually pin threads to cores with processor affinity calls.  i.e. ones that consider which socket's DRAM most of a process's working set is already on, and *create* a weak affinity based on that.  And BTW, Linux's scheduler does I think strictly follow affinity.  It will leave other cores unused even if that means multiple tasks with their affinity all set for the same core compete for it and spend a lot of time sleeping.  Try it with `time taskset -c 1 awk 'BEGIN {for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}' &` multiple times.

Comment: @PeterCordes What I meant is that it would likely be optimal to keep a thread running on the same core as long as possible and that such a feature already exists in mainstream schedulers. The kind of scheduler the OP is asking for is basically a scheduler that manages processor affinity *internally* with a slightly more complex algorithm than usual; I don't think it is possible to give a more generally applicable answer than that because the rest is highly system-dependent. I guess I could clarify my answer, though, to better distinguish between manual and "automatic" CPU affinity.

Comment: Your answer kind of implies that the Linux scheduler's affinity support is something like what you'd want: a bias towards not migrating.  This is not the case.  Linux affinity means a core will never consider running a process whose affinity mask doesn't include the bit for that core.  So it's just a hard filter not the kind of bias you'd want from a NUMA-aware scheduler where running somewhere is usually better than sitting for a long time waiting for the original core.

Comment: @PeterCordes Fair enough. I'll reformulate my answer. Also, feel free to edit it in any way you see fit - you are clearly far more knowledgeable on the subject than I am.

Comment: And BTW, NUMA cache like you mentioned (e.g. similar to Ryzen core clusters each with their own L3) is somewhat different from NUMA DRAM (same vs. different socket of a multi-socket system).  Cache will sort itself out if you migrate a task and leave it running on another core for a long time.  DRAM won't unless the OS actually copies the physical page to DRAM attached to the other socket and updates that process's page tables.  i.e. it would need software intervention to migrate the memory to the process.  (IDK if any mainstream OSes do try to consolidate the pages for a process.)